# SQL Conditional Alerts

Tags: sql, azure-alerts

I am new to SQL and use Azure Data Studio for data analysis. I am trying to setup a conditional email/text alert when a column value is greater than a given value in my SQL database. I am confused how to go about this... would I use SMTP, Azure monitor, etc.?

I have looked into Azure monitor, but it seems that it is more commonly used for alerts regarding the performance of a database and not the values contained within the database.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to send an email message from SQL Server using the sp_send_dbmail   system proc.

This is documented at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: It's not clear where you got the affirmative idea that SQL Server *specifically* is at play here when the OP makes no mention of any particular RDBMS.